# Automatic Scroll when searching in mono for android or in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a list of name in the listview, i also have a search that when i search a name it will display the one that i search. Now i just want a Automatic scroll to the one that i search. How can i do it in mono for android or in c#. If you have no idea of what mono for android is click this link : http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/sample_chapter/introduction-to-mono-for-android.htm

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can try with:

```
listview.SmoothScrollToPosition(position);
```